# Why does the Mandelbrot Set only bifurcate on real values?

Tags: chaos-theory, bifurcation

If you take a look at the figure below, the Mandelbrot Set seems to only bifurcate when it collapses into a real value (without an imaginary component). Why does this occur?

[image]

Comment: It does bifurcate from blob 1 to blob 3 at a non real complex number.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I guess I wanted to be more specific at the "main" or even periods.